# Pod 'cannot load such file' after delete and re-install

Tags: ruby, xcode, frameworks, rubygems, cocoapods

I had some major problems with my project after adding some pods to my Pod file and running pod install.

I tried to fix it after reading some `SO` questions, when nothing worked i deleted cocoa pods and re installed it using this answer: [Pod delete](https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/3723#issuecomment-141820160)

After doing that, No matter which pod command i try to execute i always get this error message:

```
admin$ pod --version
/usr/bin/pod:23:in `load': cannot load such file --    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-0.37.1/bin/pod (LoadError)
from /usr/bin/pod:23:in `<main>'
```

But when i try to list the files this is the result:

```
admin$ gem list --local | grep cocoapods
cocoapods (1.0.0)
cocoapods-clean (0.0.1)
cocoapods-core (1.0.0)
cocoapods-deintegrate (1.0.0)
cocoapods-downloader (1.0.0)
cocoapods-plugins (1.0.0)
cocoapods-search (1.0.0)
cocoapods-stats (1.0.0)
cocoapods-trunk (1.0.0)
cocoapods-try (1.0.0)
```

What am i missing over here?

Comment: Are you using a Ruby version manager like RVM or rbenv? I'm wondering if `pod` is using system installed Ruby or a user installed ruby elsewhere.

Comment: It also looks like `pod` is trying to use a version of `0.37.1` of `cocoapods`, not `1.0.0` which you have installed. You could install the older version: `gem install cocoapods -v 0.37.1`.

Comment: @Kris thanks for the comments, but I'm trying to use the pod's new version (1.0.0) thats why i deleted the previous version.

But now i do not have any cocoapods folder under '/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/' which i think i should have...

Comment: @Kris would you mind joining a chat? http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/112699/pod-cannot-load-such-file-after-delete-and-re-install

Comment: @Itzik984 I run pod install after upgrading the react-native version(0.60). It deletes react from the pods